# Adding data to Postgres database with Entity Framework Core HttpPost failing because of child table constraint

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, http-post

I am trying to add some data to a Postgres database using Entity Framework Core via a Http POST method.

The data to be added is passed in the body of my post request which looks like this:

```
{"id":42,"name":"Hans Musterman","email":"hans@gpost.com", "gender": {"id": 2,  "name": "male"}}
```

Which is exactly the structure I would get returned using a get request.

Still the insert fails with an error:

> Duplicate key value violates unique constraint "PK_Genders"

Of course the gender male already exists in the `Genders` table. What I want to do is add a user to the users table with a gender but referenced for the new user but not new created. What the system seems to do when using `DbContext` Add is trying to add User and Gender.

Is there a way to do it with a reference? Adding a User with `"gender" = null` does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should have something like `genderId` or foreign key that reference the `gender` table in the `user` model use that foreign key id (`genderId`) instead of `gender`.

eg. in you `user` object

```
{ ... "genderId": 2 }
```

Otherwise Entity Framework is going to create a new gender that is why you are getting that error

Comment: Thank you. I needed to add an genderId attribute to my C# User class. Having the gender class and the genderId as an attribute solved the Problem.